How to attach legs to the table
The four legs should be part of table, and I think should not be added to scene like its added.
Also what is good way to create new instances of legs and attach them. and the attachment should be such that the back side legs should look smaller than front. Current I am seeing only single leg, instead of 4.
If you run this code in your local you will know what I am asking.


<script type="importmap">
{
  "imports": {
    "three": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.163.0/three.module.min.js"
  }
}
</script>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'three';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(8, 0.5, 4);

// Correcting texture loading
//const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
//const texture = textureLoader.load('http://localhost:3000/wood-texture-vector-eps10-illustration-600nw-206847232.webp');
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  //map: texture
  color: 0x885511 // brown?
});

const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);


const legGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.4, 4, 0.4);

const cubeLeg = new THREE.Mesh(legGeometry, material);



scene.add(cube);
scene.add(cubeLeg);
cubeLeg.position.x = 12;
scene.add(cubeLeg);
cubeLeg.position.x = -12;
scene.add(cubeLeg);
cubeLeg.position.x = 6;
scene.add(cubeLeg);
cubeLeg.position.x = -6;

camera.position.x = 2;
camera.position.y = 4;
camera.position.z = 13;

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  //cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  //cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
</script>




scene.add(cube);
scene.add(cubeLeg);
cubeLeg.position.x = 12;
scene.add(cubeLeg);
cubeLeg.position.x = -12;
scene.add(cubeLeg);
cubeLeg.position.x = 6;
scene.add(cubeLeg);
cubeLeg.position.x = -6;

This is not how instancing works in three.js. Object3D.add (which is what's being called on the scene.add lines) does not create a copy nor an instance, so what you are doing in adding the same shape over and over, and changing only its position. This is why you're only seeing one leg.
If you want multiple legs, you can use Mesh.clone to create copies. If you want instances, look in the official docs and examples for InstancedMesh.
To answer the question in your title of how to "attach" them, you can use a Group to collect all of the shapes into a local space. When you move the Group, all child objects (whether they are Meshes or more Groups, will follow the parent Group.
// basic example:
const table = new THREE.Group();
const leg1 = new Mesh(geometry, material);
const leg2 = leg1.clone();
const leg3 = leg1.clone();
const leg4 = leg1.clone();
const tableTop = new Mesh(tabletopGeometry, material);
// position all the parts, then...
table.add(tableTop, leg1, leg2, leg3, leg4);
scene.add(table);
// from here, if you reposition "table", all parts of the table will follow


const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
const legGeometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.4, 4, 0.4);
const leg1 = new THREE.Mesh(legGeometry1, material);
leg1.position.x=2;
const leg2 = leg1.clone();
leg2.position.x=-11;
const leg3 = leg1.clone();
leg3.position.x=11;
const leg4 = leg1.clone();
leg4.position.x=21;
const table = new THREE.Group();
table.add(cube, leg1, leg2, leg3, leg4);
scene.add(table);   Try this, Now there are four mesh but each mesh has different shape ?

@user204069 Incorrect. leg1, leg2, leg3, and leg4 all share the same geometry, and are the same shape. However, what's you're seeing is called "perspective projection." Your camera has an 80° Field of View, which is quite wide. Objects toward the sides will warp and bend due to this perspective. Try a smaller value (like 25), and you'll see less warping at the edges of the frame. Also remember you can use camera.lookAt( Vector3 ) to make your camera look at something. Use this to get a better view of your table/scene.
